# Active Storage and Cloudinary : Using already uploaded images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cloudinary, rails-activestorage

In my seeds, I usually use `Cloudinary` and `Active Storage` by attaching new pictures to my object:

```rb
file = URI.open("https://my_image_location")
model_instance.photo.attach(io: file, filename: "file_name")
```

Problem is: each time we run the seed, a new upload of the image is done by `Active Storage`, and my `Cloudinary` account is filled with duplicate images.

I want to fix this problem by storing my images on Cloudinary, and making `Active Storage` use it directly without duplicating it, but I have no clue how to do that. (I was able to back in the days I was using `CarrierWave`, so it's a little frustrating :/)

Do you have any idea how to do that?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Public id generation is handled by Active Storage, and thus you cannot choose the public id. This is one of the limitations of an Active Storage flow.

Since this is only for testing, you may be able to delete all the images from the database after your testing is done with a few commands in the rails shell.